# How to review a short answer that correctly answers a question

Tags: discussion

I often don't know how to review a short answer because the audits often show that they are of low quality. If a very brief answer does help someone to solve their problem and is correct should I mark it as 'No action needed', 'Low quality' or skip the question. I'm afraid of failing the audit is why I ask.

Comment: If the answer is correct it is not 'low quality'. If you see a post, it was long enough to clear the minimal length requirements to be posted, we have no other requirements on length.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay, thanks I will keep that in mind.

Comment: _"If the answer is correct it is not 'low quality'."_ I dispute this. It might not be **Very** Low Quality, as in the flag, but "Here try this `badlyFormattedCode(thatHacks, aroundTheProblem, butItWorks!)`" is definitely not a high quality answer.

Comment: Note that there is a scheduled job that puts answers which are mostly code, and short, into the low quality review queue. @MartijnPieters, is there a disconnect between your statement and this automated system?

Answer (score 8):

An answer can be accurate and solve the problem at hand while being short.

Comment: Can you please add a TL;DR to this?

Comment: tl;dr: Good short answers are fine.

Comment: answer good; words bad.

Comment: Good, short, ok.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​