# Should I post a question asking to confirm knowledge?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

Every now and then after I've done research on a topic/issue, I would like validation on my findings. How should I phrase a post like this to make sure it is a beneficial post for Stack Overflow?

For example, today I've done research and I've been working on a post, but I keep reworking it and sometimes even debate with myself if I should post it at all.

Below you'll see a subset of drafts I created for a post and the reasons why I decided not to use them.

1. "Could people please confirm that it is not possible to create a stored procedure in a SQL Server that would [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) data from two tables passed into the stored procedure as parameters?"

   Does not promote a good technical answer; only answers with a simple "No, it is not".
2. "How would you create a stored procedure in a SQL Server that would ETL data from two tables passed into the stored procedure as parameters?"

   Goes against what I've found, and in the past I've gotten responses along the lines of "You don't understand X and it is impossible. Do more research. [Downvote + close]"
3. "Is there an alternative or workaround for the inability to create a stored procedure in a SQL Server that would ETL data from two tables passed into the stored procedure as parameters?"

   This is very vague and lacks information to constrain answers. Possible answers include: you could write a C# script; you could use program X; Rework your previous queries like this; etc.

The kinds of answers I'm trying to invite are of the type:

- "What you've found is valid for versions up to and including X, but in version (X+1) they have added Y that allows you to do this."
- "You can't pass in tables directly to your stored procedure due to them being readonly, but you can pass in the table name as a string and use it in an executed string query. What you should be aware of is: [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, and reduced performance."

Comment: Before anything else: Thank you for asking on Meta first.

Comment: Not sure if it applies to your case, but you might want to consider just asking the general question and then self-answering it. Your mileage may vary depending on the topic, though.

Comment: Related: [Should I answer “is it possible?” type of questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270933/215552)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should you respond to a "Yes or No" question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337245/how-should-you-respond-to-a-yes-or-no-question)

Comment: Typically, "How to solve problem X" questions work very well. Don't fall into the XY trap and think you already know the answer to your problem and simply want it confirmed. Always ask for a problem you have, even if the problem is only that you are not sure about something. If so, find out why you aren't sure, then ask exactly about that.

Comment: "Is there an alternative or workaround for the inability.." That probably best reflects your current knowledge but it will depend on what exactly you want to achieve. As such it would need more clarity, i.e. an exact description what the alternative is supposed to deliver (it can't do the same as the thing that is impossible). Basically a problem statement is needed.

Comment: @gnat That target doesn't seem right. The OP here is looking for ways to avoid *asking* a Yes or No question in the first place; not how to answer an existing question of that nature.

Comment: Haven't we seen a very similar question here on MSO recently (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: Seems like the whole two tables ETL thing is irrelevant, and you're just asking "How do I pass a table to a stored procedure" (if you can pass one, you can pass two), which is an OK question, if it wouldn't be a duplicate (which it is, of course).

Comment: @ErikA - From my research you can't modify (the L in ETL) tables passed in as parameters to a function or a stored procedure. On a side note if you know how I'd love for you to help me with this.

Comment: @Mandelbrotter I don't understand why a table wouldn't be modifiable. If you ask a proper question, feel free to notify me here (without the ETL stuff, just "how do I pass a table to a stored procedure that modifies the table"). And I don't really understand the issue, as long as you're okay with dynamic SQL this should be trivial.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) states:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …[...] there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

A question that asks to confirm knowledge is close to this if it has no clear yes-or-no-answer. You also need to be careful to not post an opinion-based question.

The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) also states:

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - [...]
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions

You are free to post "unusual" questions, ones that don't follow the typical Q&A-style. But you need to make sure your question results in something constructive. You need to think about how a question might also benefit others, not just you.

It's a good idea to write your question together with the problem. This avoids your question to be about an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It enables people to address the problem and not just to confirm your knowledge. It also raises the chances that other people benefit from the Q&A as people usually search for how to solve a problem and not if some knowledge is valid.

You might want to post the question on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). Questions that are unusual (but still of higher quality) are better received if the readers are enthusiasts/experts in the domain. If you post it on Stack Overflow, then it might be seen by some people who have no clue and (close-)vote it based on its appearance.

Comment: I agreed that posting this to DBA is probably the better option. In my experience they're very helpful if the question is well thought out and will go out of their way to help

Answer (score 33):

Perhaps you could post a self-answered question.  If you *think* you know the answer, post it as the answer, and leave a comment to the extent of "this reflects my understanding as of *date here*, but please correct me if I'm wrong".  That way, future users who have the same original question but haven't done the research will simply find your question and your answer (or a better answer, if one was posted).

Comment: I like this option and I'm willing to try it out and see.

Answer (score 9):

## Yes

A long time ago, I can't find it now, I've read an excellent question here, where the OP was asking something along the lines of "Am I asking too detailed questions? I get answers like a simple no".

An excellent answer passed on this nugget of wisdom that, if you can write a question with sufficient details, clarity, context and nuances that it can be answered with a single "yes" or "no", **this is an excellent question and it should most definitely be asked**.

I personally believe that confirming knowledge is of paramount importance in evolving as a programmer and we should absolutely allow, encourage and want questions that help it.

Comment: 'if you can write a question [that] can be answered with a single "yes" or "no", this is an excellent question' - given this statement I find it very amusing that you started your answer with a single "yes" and then wrote three more paragraphs.

Comment: @Sellyme It's just a footnote :)

Comment: @Sellyme I have already played the short answer trick, I have to vary a bit ;-) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379609/576767

Answer (score 7):

I think your #1 and #3 are pretty much the same, and an invocation of [Moore's Law](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law):

> the best way to get the right answer on the internet is not to ask a question; it's to post the wrong answer

If you want to know how to do X, ask *"How to do X?"*, not *"I believe it's impossible to do X, change my mind"*.

In accordance with [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you *definitely* should show your research, even if that caused you to believe that what you're asking for is impossible, as to prevent downvotes. And you definitely should explain very explicitly what you want, to prevent close-votes.

Do not hesitate to post a question if you believe the answer to be "No.".

So your question, if you'd post it, would look something like this:

> I want to write a stored procedure to perform [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) on two tables passed as parameters.
>
> By "ETL" I mean I want the SP to do X, and by "tables passed as parameters" I mean [table-valued parameters|table names]. The signature would look something like this:
>
> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE etl (parameter list)
> SELECT ... FROM ...
> ```
>
> My research [link, link, link] showed that it's not possible because of [reason], and I've tried to implement it as such, and indeed, I got error
>
> > Cannot foo the bar
>
> So how can I do this, if at all?

Comment: I see what you did there.

Answer (score 6):

### If you want to know if X is possible ask that:

"Is it possible to do X? From my reading here and here and here, it appears not. Am I missing something?"

Shows research, has a clear question. Win.

### If you want a workaround, ask that

"I'm trying to achieve X. It seems you can't do it directly because of Y. What's a good workaround, given constraints Z? I thought of trying A but it seems really clumsy and convoluted, is there a better way?"

Again, shows effort, and is clear what you want to know.

Comment: Except your second option may get closed due to the use of "better" ;) Some find it opinionated.

Comment: Well, by prefacing it with "clumsy and convoluted" you're defining what "better" means in the context.

Comment: I've had this discussion with close voters. I agree with you, but that doesn't keep a post open. It's my impression that a post is less likely to get closed with the phrasing "is there another way"

Answer (score 4):

I'd certainly like to see this normalized on the site.  The types of problems users here deal with can often have a dozen or more possible causes or solutions.  When you take a rigorous problem-solving approach to them, it's helpful both to be able to quickly exclude the things that you are *mostly* sure are not the problem, or to quickly correct any wrong assumptions you have.  For example,

Q: "My program keeps throwing a type error.  The `Wooble.flerb()` function can never return a boolean, correct?"

A: "Yes, that's correct.  The documentation (link) states that it can only ever return a string."

or

Q: "I'm trying to architect a Zorpler.  Most of the approaches I can think of would be hugely difficult, but then it occured to me that it would be much easier to do if I could implement reverse-gomping in the Bogglr framework.  I'm not a Bogglr expert, but I don't think that's possible, is it?"

A: "No, it is possible with a little effort.  The Wifflex project does that, you can read through their GitHub (link) to see how they did it."

These are well-defined questions with clear, supportable answers that are likely to be helpful to both the asker and to future searchers.  They should be welcome on the site.

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I ...?

I would almost always suggest trying to phrase a question as "How do I..." (or "How can I" or "How to").

You can still add the research you've done or any conclusion you've reached in the question. You can also add "If it's not possible, is there any alternative or workaround?" to the body of your question.

- **That's probably what most people wondering the same thing will Google.**

  This might be the most important factor.

  If you phrase your title in a fundamentally different way, people are less likely to find the question and less likely to think it would provide an answer to their question.
- **It's the most succinct.**

  Neither "Could people please confirm that it is not possible" nor "Is there an alternative or workaround for the inability" really adds anything to the question beyond what "How do I" would (except a lot of pointless words).

  If it's not possible, one can simply answer "How do I" with "It is not possible because X, Y, Z". If there is a workaround, one can answer "It is not possible [because X, Y, Z], but you can ...".
- **The answers can actually *be* answers and be direct.**

  A simple "You are right" is not really much of an answer. That's basically just saying your "answer" is correct.

  "You are wrong" is also not really ideal. I think of this as kind of backtracking to the point where you assumed or concluded something incorrectly and going in another direction. It's an unnecessary step if you can instead just ask your question starting at the point they went back to. This is maybe only a minor factor, but still.

#### Post a self-answer

This was already mentioned in another answer, but I'm just mentioning it here for completeness.

If you've already done a bunch of research finding it's not possible, this would probably make sense to put in an answer (which you can potentially remove if someone posts an answer showing that it is actually possible).

The question should still stand up on its own merit though. I might also suggest posting a comment on the question saying you self-answered, as this may make people less likely to downvote for insufficient research.

#### An [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

I'm not sure about your question specifically, but often if you get yourself into a situation where what you're trying to do is not possible, you need to take a step back to the problem you were actually trying to solve with that approach.

What is the original problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need to "create a stored procedure to ETL data from two tables as parameters"? Does it have to be a stored procedure specifically? Do the tables need to be parameters?

Maybe it would make sense to instead ask "How do I ETL data from two tables in a stored procedure", or even just "How do I ETL data from two tables". Okay, the latter one probably doesn't make sense here (and maybe the former doesn't either), but it should still demonstrate the point I'm trying to make.

You can then say that you tried to solve it with a stored procedure with two tables as parameters, but it seems that's not actually possible (with a short minimal example demonstrating that).

#### Give us some data

I would suggest generally trying to include some actual example input data you have and output data you want to allow others to see what you're actually trying to accomplish (for SQL, an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) tends to be helpful). If you simply post a generic "How do I X" without any data, this may get closed as unclear. Although you should try to refrain from making the question you're actually asking *too* specific to your problem, as this commonly happens (especially for SQL questions, I feel) and comes at the expense of helping others with similar problems.

Answer (score -13):

1: I think the answer is yes, but I am not sure. You will probably need some triggers and `EXEC` of a string created with the procedural script. It won't be very beautiful, but it could work.

2 and 3: I think this question is okay. Explain the problems you've found. Explain what you want, what you tried and why it did not work. If it is really not possible, then the answer will probably say also this.

In general, there is *nothing* in the rules which would forbid question validations. This is not a valid closure reason. But where the expected answer is only a single bit (yes or no), then it is not a very useful content. It might cause downvotes or unfair (but possible) closures. So I suggest to package the question as (2) or (3).

If you find the treatment of the questions too hostile on the SO, you have the option to ask your questions from a secondary account. On this way, you can prevent the problem of that you will have downvoted, not deletable question on your profile, or that you will need to use the `/contact` form to ask the team to disassociate your question from your account. Using secondary accounts for this purpose is officially accepted (with some limits).

Comment: "Using secondary accounts for this purpose is officially accepted" I am decently sure that using a secondary account to avoid rep loss is not allowed, as it circumvents the rating system. Adding a source for this claim would be helpful.

Comment: According to [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388985/10871900), it is not forbidden.

Comment: @dan1st Thanks. Don't worry, it is not a problem for the mods to delete my comments and to leave "MisterMiyagi"'s one here (while also they know very well the FAQ and the multi-accounts rules). Probably also this comment will soon disappear. And, this answer has already got 1 delete votes (100% power misuse), and somehow I have the impression that also this will be found okay.

Comment: @dan1st "not forbidden" is another pair of shoes than "officially accepted". Since the purpose of the secondary account would be to avoid loss of rep/privilege, it seems to veer into "circumvent system-imposed restrictions" territory.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It does not work on this way. The rep loss happens on the secondary account, so it is not avoided. What can be interpreted as misusing multiple accounts: if the secondary account gets a q-ban, then it is a misuse to post further questions from the first (or from a terciary) account. The existence of similar edge cases are mentioned in the post (*"with some limits"*). But I think, we both know, that not this was the cause of your massive downing. The real cause was *that I suggested to use secondary accounts to avoid you*. The exact details of the relevant rules are unrelated.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Btw, I am really curious, what behavior do you expect from me after such "events". Obviously the last what you can expect, that I become silent or stop avoiding to suggest the usage of secondary accounts. I hope you understand this.

Comment: As stated earlier, I expect a source for the claim that using a secondary for the sole purpose of avoiding negative rating for the main account is officially accepted.